# How do you use python to do file memory map insertion without overwriting?

Tags: python, memory, insert, mmap

I have been trying to figure out how to use python's mmap module to do insertion of data at specific locations and not overwrite the data already mapped.

I have figured out how to write data to a memory mapped file and even at the location I want it to be inserted at.  The data being inserted is regex'd hostname data out of a large 1 GB file, transforming it to lowercase with an appended domain suffix and then using that data to plugin to a certain area in the file mapped into memory.  Right now, it writes it in the correct location, but overwrites my data.

**Data in file I want to parse ( the real file will be 800+ megs to 1 gig)**

```
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0001"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0002"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0003"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0004"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0005"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0006"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0007"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">localhost</tag>
```

**Python Code I am using to attempt to do the insertions:**

```
import sys
import mmap
import re

# Regex to rip out the hostname between the ReportHost and HostProperties tag
myregex = r'<ReportHost\sname="(.*?)"><HostProperties>'
# Used later on to do a mm.find to find the index location in the mapped file on first occurance as I need to rename one of the tag values at a time per hostname.  Its a 1 to 1 match of having a <ReportHost and then a host-fqdn after.
fqdntag = "<tag name=\"host-fqdn\">localhost"

# List used to store the carved out transformed with suffix host values
FQDNH = []

def main(mm):

    # Find and carve out host names
    dm = re.findall(myregex, mm)

    for a in dm:
    print a
        host = str.lower(a+".ad.something.com")
    # Store hosts with suffix into list
        FQDNH.append(host)

#attempt to resize the memory mapped file so there is room for insertion
    newsize = filelenb + hostnum * 1000000
    mm.resize(newsize)

    for host in FQDNH:
        print "New File Size ", filelenb
        print host
    # calculate size of memory mapped file
        size = len(mm)
    # calculate size of hostname
        length = len(host)
    print length
    # find first occurance host-fqdn tag
        fqdnindx = mm.find(fqdntag)
    # calculate the first occurance index value and added hostname length
        awindx = fqdnindx + length
        print "Current Position: ", mm.tell()
    # move data to allow for insertion?  dest, src, count? not really sure how this works for insertion
        mm.move(awindx, fqdnindx, 27)
    # seek index location and move 22 spaces to insert the full qualified domain name (fqdn)
        mm.seek(fqdnindx+22)
    # insert fqdn into memory mapped file
        mm.write(host)
    # flush changes from memory file back to disk
    mm.flush()
    mm.seek(0)
    mm.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f=sys.argv[1]
    fi = open(f, 'r+')
    mm = mmap.mmap(fi.fileno(), 0)
    fi.close()
    main(mm)
```

**Results I get, which appear to overwrite the data:**

```
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0001"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0001.ad.something.comlocal="lnm02a0002"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0002.ad.something.comlocal="lnm02a0003"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0003.ad.something.comlocal="lnm02a0004"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0004.ad.something.comlocal="lnm02a0005"><HostProperties
```

**What I actually want:**

```
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0001"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0001.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0002"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0002.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0003"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0003.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0004"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0004.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0005"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0005.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0006"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0006.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
<ReportHost name="lnm02a0007"><HostProperties>
<tag name="host-fqdn">lnm02a0007.ad.something.comlocalhost</tag>
```